# Не задается сглаживание анимации

Tags: css3, html, css

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с анимацией CSS3 - почему-то не задается сглаживание анимации. Задается linear, а отображается как ease-out. Вот код:

```
<style>
.loader{
    border:35px #ddd solid;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border-radius:185px;
    -webkit-border-radius:185px
}

@keyframes rotate{from{transform:rotate(0deg)}to{transform:rotate(360deg)}}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)}}

.loader{
    animation-name:rotate;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    transition-timing-function:linear
}
.loader{
    -webkit-animation-name:rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear
}
</style>

<div class="loader"></div>
```

Что я делаю не так?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Количество ответов говорит о количестве знающих CSS 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напиши просто

```
.loader{
    -webkit-animation:rotate 1s infinite linear;
}
```

А вообще [использовать -webkit и -moz расширения - моветон](http://itc.ua/news/apple-i-google-podverglis-kritike-iz-za-dvizhka-webkit/):

> Потому рекомендуется разработчикам сайтов прекратить оптимизировать свои сайты исключительно для браузеров на базе движка WebKit.

Comment: О_О Вах, шаман! А в чем была проблема?  
А вообще, у меня прописаны все расширения, просто не хотел сюда кидать всю эту простыню.

Comment: По поводу причины намекну так: замените в своем коде `-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear` на `-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear`

Comment: Вот и доверяй после такого копипасте из интернетов. =(  
Еще раз спасибо.